# NAV web service throws "cannot enter 'Order' in Integer"

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dynamics-nav

I'm trying to add a **purchase line** to a **purchase order** in Dynamics NAV (2009 R2 Classic) using **web services**, but I'm running into a peculiar issue.

Creating a purchase line without defining a `No` works sans problem. Only when I define a `No`, like in the example below, I get the following exception:

> You cannot enter 'Order' in Integer.

```vb
Dim purchaseLine = New PurchaseLine

purchaseLine.Document_No = myPurchaseHeader
purchaseLine.Document_Type = Document_Type.Order
purchaseLine.Document_TypeSpecified = True
purchaseLine.Line_No = 1000
purchaseLine.Line_NoSpecified = True
purchaseLine.Type = Type.Item
purchaseLine.TypeSpecified = True
purchaseLine.No = myItemNo ' Defining No seems to cause the problem.

purchaseLineService.Create(purchaseLine)
```

I've tried creating the purchase line first, without defining `No`. Which works, but updating it with `No` defined, results in the same.

```vb
purchaseLine.No = myItemNo

purchaseLineService.Update(purchaseLine)
```

It was suggested somewhere to try using `1` and `"1"` for `Document_Type`, but that didn't work either.

I've also followed the steps described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/freddyk/archive/2009/05/28/handling-sales-orders-from-page-based-web-services-in-nav-2009sp1-and-rtm.aspx), without success.

While googling I found [some](http://www.msdynamics.de/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=17428) [forums](http://www.mibuso.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=49114) where people had a similar problem, but they didn't get me closer to a solution.

Any idea's?

**Edit:**

After doing some more research and testing, I've concluded that my NAV installation is incomplete/flawed/messed up. More details [here](https://community.dynamics.com/nav/f/34/t/178758).

Comment: This looks like there is an error in Nav code. Mibuso from your link suggests the same. I believe you have Page (not codeunit) published as service, so check if you can create Purchase Lines via this page when opened in RTC Client. Another question: are you using standard solution (like Cronus) or trying to connect to heavily modified customer's solution?

Comment: I have indeed published a (self-made) Page as a web service. Unfortunately, I don't have access to RTC Client, only Classic. Our solution is an "upgrade" from NAV 5.

Comment: What you mean by "don't have access"? You cant build a house if you don't have access to construction site.

Comment: I'm being forced to run before I can walk here :-(... As far as I know, there's no RTC client available, it was never installed. Our external partner has added the necessary objects (like Form 810 Web Services) to our Classic client.

Comment: Just thinking out loud...How about exposing a codeunit with a procedure to that you pass in the values needed to create your PO and have that procedure create the PO.

Comment: After doing some more research and testing, I've concluded that my NAV installation is incomplete/flawed/messed up. More details [here](https://community.dynamics.com/nav/f/34/t/178758). So the solution lies elsewhere.

Comment: Read your posts. Sad upgrade story. Yes it is very impropper way to upgrade. If the solution is highly customized then you cant just import objects from new version of Cronus. If you have no other way, try @DougJ.Huras suggestion. Publish Codeunit with function that accept all parameters you need to create order and create it using table variable (validate fields and insert record).

Comment: More things to try is to check versions of your Nav server (at this point you have to have one if you have abillity to publish WS). Maybe there is an newer build where this problem is fixed. This happens from time to time. And as far as you can invoke WS means you can have RTC. You just need to install it from distributive wich you probably don't have but your partner does. Maybe it's even lies somewhere on your server as it is the same distributive from wich Nav server is installed.

Comment: I've pushed the issue to people higher up the food chain. We'll be upgrading to NAV 2013 or 2015 next year anyway. The web service story will probably get postponed till then.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is corrected with this change in codeunit 422, function FormatValue.

```
//*** BEGIN
//  EVALUATE(OptionNo,FORMAT(fldRef.VALUE))
  IF NOT EVALUATE(OptionNo,FORMAT(fldRef.VALUE)) THEN
    EXIT(FORMAT(FldRef.VALUE));
//*** END
```